# Combine 2 tables extract all values from Table2 type2 and exclude duplicate column value from Table1 & use values from table2 in Table 3 type2

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I have 2 tables. I wish to join these tables and record historical data (type2) and update the StartDate and EndDate accordingly.
id 'E7C7' has three entries in Table1(type2) and one in Table2(type1). 
Table2 has the most current data.

The default StartDate for data in Table1 is 1/1/2018 and the default EndDate is 9999-12-31.

E7C7 has changed titles 3 times since 1/1/2018. The result set should include all past and present data for E7C7 and any new entries from Table2. The Result set will flag old records as [current] = 'N' and new records [current] = 'Y'.  Table1 also contains most current data for changed records. The default StartDate for Table2 is GetDate() and the default EndDate is 9999-12-31

```
    TABLE1                  
id      mod_date    old_value   new_value           
E7C7    01/10/18    FSA         Sr FS           
E7C7    01/25/18    Sr FS       FS          
E7C7    02/01/18    FS          FSA         
EA23    01/15/18    SFA         FM          

    TABLE2                  
id     number   last_name    title          
2DB3    12344   A            SLS        
C655    12227   L            SA    
D0F7    12228   K            I-CSR          
E7C7    11937   H            FSA            
EA23    1267    S            FM         
FCF1    139     A            CAR            

    RESULT SET           
id     number   last_name   title   StartDate   EndDate Current
2DB3    12344   A           SLS     02/24/2018  12/31/9999  Y
C655    12227   L           SA      02/24/2018  12/31/9999  Y
D0F7    12228   K           I-CSR   02/24/2018  12/31/9999  Y
E7C7    11937   H           FSA     01/25/18    12/31/9999  Y
E7C7    11937   H           FS      01/10/18    01/25/18    N
E7C7    11937   H           Sr FS   01/1/2018   01/10/18    N
EA23    1267    S           SFA     01/1/2018   01/15/18    N
EA23    1267    S           FM      01/15/18    12/31/9999  Y
FCF1    139     A           CAR     02/24/2018  12/31/9999  Y
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL?

Comment: I am using MS SQL. This for an initial load OF Results table(Table3) in SSIS

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am expecting E7C7 entries (Two entries with title FSA) four times in expected result set. Could you please correct me?

Comment: Bhatia, this is correct my code is not working as desired. I want to eliminate one of the most current since there are two and enter correct StartDate(1/25/2018) and EndDate(12/31/999) as in the desired results table. I am using SQL2017

Comment: @CharlesPhillips, you should show how your data looks for ids `2DB3, C655, D0F7` in `TABLE1`

Comment: They do not exist in table1 only table2 since table1 one only contains audits. – Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this query. I wrote it according to your expected result

```
declare @t1 table (id varchar(10), mod_date date, old_value varchar(10), new_value varchar(10))
insert into @t1
values ('E7C7', '20180110', 'FSA', 'Sr FS'),('E7C7', '20180125', 'Sr FS', 'FS')
    ,('E7C7', '20180201', 'FS', 'FSA'),('EA23', '20180115', 'SFA', 'FM')

declare @t2 table (id varchar(10), number int, last_name varchar(10), title varchar(10))
insert into @t2
values ('2DB3', '12344', 'A', 'SLS'), ('C655', '12227', 'L', 'SA')
    , ('D0F7', '12228', 'K', 'I-CSR'), ('E7C7', '11937', 'H', 'FSA')
    , ('EA23', '1267', 'S', 'FM'), ('FCF1', '139', ' A', 'CAR')

;with cte as (
    select
        *, prev_date = lag(mod_date) over (partition by id order by mod_date, order_)
        , cnt = count(*) over (partition by id)
        , rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by mod_date, order_)
    from (
        select 
            a.id, a.number, a.last_name, a.title, b.mod_date, b.old_value, b.new_value, order_ = 1
        from 
            @t2 a
            left join @t1 b on a.id = b.id
        union all
        select
            t.id, q.number, q.last_name, null, t.mod_date, t.old_value, null, 0
        from (
            select
                *, cnt = count(*)over (partition by id)
            from
                @t1
            ) t
            join @t2 q on t.id = q.id
        where
            cnt = 1
    ) t
)
select
    id, number, last_name
    , title = coalesce(new_value, title, old_value)
    , StartDate = isnull(prev_date, iif(cnt = 1, '20180224', '20180101'))
    , EndDate = iif(cnt > rn, mod_date, '99991231') 
    , [Current] = iif(cnt = rn, 'Y', 'N')
from
    cte
order by id, rn desc
```

Output

```
id      number  last_name   title    StartDate    EndDate       Current
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2DB3    12344   A           SLS      2018-02-24   9999-12-31    Y
C655    12227   L           SA       2018-02-24   9999-12-31    Y
D0F7    12228   K           I-CSR    2018-02-24   9999-12-31    Y
E7C7    11937   H           FSA      2018-01-25   9999-12-31    Y
E7C7    11937   H           FS       2018-01-10   2018-01-25    N
E7C7    11937   H           Sr FS    2018-01-01   2018-01-10    N
EA23    1267    S           FM       2018-01-15   9999-12-31    Y
EA23    1267    S           SFA      2018-01-01   2018-01-15    N
FCF1    139  A  CAR 2018-02-24  9999-12-31  Y
```